# Getting an undefined value at Angular from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, ejs

I am passing the values from HTML to Angular using ng-modal but its giving me undefined at Angular. I am passing the value through ng-click to pass value to the Angular, where I am making use of the firebug options to check my values at Angular.

```
 <div class ="row"> 
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
<p>Bid Price<input type= "text" class="form-control" name="Nbid" id="Nbid" ng-model ="Nbid"  pattern="[0-9]" style="width:90px" ></p>
```

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1"> <br> 
<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="placeBid(result.ITEM_CODE ,Nbid, result.ITEM_NAME, result.ITEM_DESC);" style="width:120px"> Place Bid</button></p></div</div>
```

On Angular side the code is :

```
$scope.placeBid = function(ITEMCODE, Nbid, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_DESC){
$scope.value = ITEMCODE;
$scope.bidpr = Nbid;
$scope.ITEM_NAME = ITEM_NAME;
$scope.ITEM_DESC = ITEM_DESC;

console.log($scope.value);
console.log($scope.bidpr);
console.log($scope.ITEM_NAME);
console.log($scope.ITEM_DESC);
```

On Firebug console I am getting this values printed:

```
console.log($scope.value);     --->  15
console.log($scope.bidpr);     ---->  undefined
console.log($scope.ITEM_NAME);  ----> J.K TWINGING
console.log($scope.ITEM_DESC); ---- > SAHIL MON  MYSTERY
```

I am not sure where I am making mistake in the code that I can see the value of the bid as undefined. [image: Firebug Picture]

[image: HTML view]

Comment: Is the value of `Nbid` inside `ng-click` defined? As in does these items exist in the same scope/controller?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek ng-click="placeBid(result.ITEM_CODE ,Nbid, result.ITEM_NAME, result.ITEM_DESC) Isn't this correct? I passed the value in the ng-click

Comment: your code looks fine...unless you are messing with multiple controllers. In that case `Nbid` can be looked for up in hierarchy if not found in local `$scope`. Can you try building a plunker out of your code.

Comment: I am using a single controller and that too defined in the body of the HTML
<body ng-app="bid" ng-controller="bidController">

on the Angular side 
var app = angular.module("bid", []);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `pattern="[0-9]"` attribute in your `input`, according to these only you can put just one digit in it, so I think you are put more than one digit in it therefor the `ng-model` lost its data.
Remove `pattern="[0-9]"` and try again.

Comment: @maverick Your welcome ;) so choose my answer as acceptable answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ng-model there is no need for you tu pass it's value as a function parameter. You can access the current value directly on the controller via

```
$scope.Nbid;
```

Reference: [NgModel Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)